# App crashed with base.apk!libmonochrome.so

Tags: android, webview, crash

We are experiencing large number of crashes recently especially in Samsung, LG devices (mostly Android 10, 11).

The crash report in Play Console says :
backtrace:
#00  pc 0000000001bb1ed8  /data/app/~~8ql0flEwCl8tpQXEDqYp-w==/com.google.android.webview-nHOdMOK9WY-Nv2RB5HLF7A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x352000)

#00  pc 0000000002a299cc  /data/app/com.android.chrome-vWnAqmlPpzO9GGYC3iaeyg==/base.apk (offset 0xd49000)

Has anyone else been experiencing this and can anyone point out to what might be causing such a thing?

Comment: This is mostly due to a Chrome / WebView bug that pops up every once in a while. I assume your app uses Ads so the Banner Ads use WebView internally which might have been the cause.
(Even if you do not use Ads, there might be some other library which might be using WebView somewhere).
There's nothing you can do particularly except waiting for the team to push an update & the users update the WebView app.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue today. If anyone found a solution, please let me know.

Comment: same solution from Varad, uninstall Android System Webview update

Comment: I have also got this error on Vitals

Comment: We need to notify our affected users about the resolve that themselves need to do.
Is there a way to catch this excepton and notify.

Answer (score 13):

Recently I experienced same issue on webview.

Problem was from last update of `Android System Webview`. When I disabled it, App webviews were working properly.

So the only solution we got was to inform & direct users via notification to update their `Chrome` and `Android System Webview` apps to latest version, to overcome this issue.

I hope this might help others.

Comment: Are you talking about this thread https://support.google.com/android/thread/103561027 ?

Comment: Yes yes, but didn't knew they made this thread. Thanks for posting.

Comment: so how do we get to know users who are experiencing this issue, so we can notify them only.

Comment: @VikasPandey if you are storing your users ID in vitals/crashlytics/server crash logs, and you have user ID and their FCM mapping. You can send notification to all those users. In my case, our userbase is huge and almost every users where affected whose `Android System Webview` was on auto update. So we notified every users with steps to update their `Android System Webview`

Answer (score 0):

Play Console only shows: "[base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so]" and that it last occured on an Android 11 device.
No further information.
We don't use a Webview.
MAYBE the Google Map uses one.

Since only one user was affected in the last 28 days (5 crashes) and we have a working customer support, I ignore the error as long as nobody reports. Maybe I did that myself when testing and the crash isn't even noticeable...

Comment: I do recall that Google Maps uses webviews~